# Magento2: How to remove Paypal Credit button from product detail page?

Tags: payment-methods, payment, paypal, magento2.3.5-p1

I have enabled the "Display on Product Details Page" to "Yes" from the admin section in the PayPal payment method, but I need only the PayPal icon, not the required PayPal Credit Icon on the product page and other(cart page and mini cart).

I am not able to find any setting for this icon in admin, Can anyone help me how to remove this from admin.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Check this image and set setting according to hide button.

Comment: I am not able to find this method in my setup http://prntscr.com/tvrwvh

Comment: Which magento version you used? click on Other Payment options and check.

Comment: I am using Magento ver. 2.3.5-p2

Comment: I gave you a screenshot of Magento 2.3.5-p1 with no customisation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to disabled
Sales > Payment Method > Update Merchant Country to US

Then move to

Basic Settings - PayPal Express Checkout > Advanced Settings > Frontend Experince Settings > Features > Disable Funding Option
Select PayPal Credit to disabled it.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Disable below option from settings do cache flush & it works fine.

Enable In-Context Checkout Experience